# Change working of inventory quantity increment magento

Tags: magento, inventory

I have trap in the problem scenario is describe blow

According to the requirement i want force the user to enter the product quantity in multiple of minimum quantity for example if min qty is 50 then its next order for that product will be 100.

I able achieve this functionality by enable *QTY INCREMENTS* option set to **YES**. But this will work only when the *MANAGE STOCK* option is SET to YES

BUT i want this option is worked when *MANAGE STOCK* option is set to **NO**.

I am using Magento ver. 1.5.1.0

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible even with ver. 1.6.1

Comment: Any specific reason to why it's not possible? (A more detailed answer?)